# Get largest text field ID with jQuery

Tags: jquery

All,
I have the following hidden field on  my page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="timeline_num[]" id="timeline_num" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

There can be multiple of these on the page. There can be anywhere from 1 to 100 or possibly more and there can be any amount within that range. So for example if there are 49 of these on my page I'd like to find the highest one. So in that example, I'd like my jQuery to return 49.

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the largest `$i` guaranteed to be the last one in the DOM?

Comment: @SiGanteng Yes, until I add another row dynamically.

Comment: After you add a row dynamically, do you want this jQuery function to return 49 or 50? Does the newly added input get a name of `timeline_num[50]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[name="timeline_num[]"]').length
```

It will return you the number of elements with `timeline_num[]` as `name` attribute.

```
$('[name="timeline_num[]"]').last().val()
```

It will return you the value of the last element with `timeline_num[]` as `name` attribute (I'm assuming that you are in a loop because of the `$i` so the last one is the biggest).